# creating an array of random numbers

Tags: java

I am simply trying to create an array of ten numbers between 0 and 12. My program is giving me "[I@e8bb762" as output. Please help. This is my program.

```
public class Array {
  public static void main (String [] args){

    //variable
    int [] row = new int [12];

    for(int i= 0; i < 12; i++){
      row [i] = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
    }



    System.out.println(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the way your are printing it to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row))`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are objects in Java that don't override `Object`'s `toString()` method, which is responsible for the output you see.

Use the [`Arrays.toString` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29), suited for converting arrays to strings.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply print each number in your array within the same loop you already have right after the number is generated. In your loop add the line:

```
System.out.print(row[i] + ",");
```